# springsecurity: using CSRF token obtained from CrossOrigin REST service to POST data

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, same-origin-policy

I have this REST service on `domainA`:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins={"http://domainB"})
@RequestMapping(value="/csrf", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
CsrfToken getCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken)request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    return token;
}
```

Then I want to obtain CSRF token from above service (by using javascript on `domainB`) and add it to a `<form action="http://domainA>` on `domainB` and send this form to `domainA` (it is a simple form that has a submit button).

The problem is I get HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden.

As the opposite: when I manually set the `_csrf` value (obtained manually in the other browser tab pointing to `domainA/csrf`) in the `<form action="http://domainA>` and submit it then it works.

The difference which I noticed is that when I manually refresh browser's tab `domainA/csrf` then I get constantly the same value (and this value works), but when the `domainA/csrf` is obtained by the javascript from the `domainB` it is each time different and when using it - it does not work.

Can anyone help?

---

domainA: www.fridayweekend.com/rest/csrf

domainB: www.friwee.com/register (hit F12 and observe what call to www.fridayweekend.com/rest/csrf returns....)

Answer (score 0):

As @dur said - the problem was in the JavaScript code. I used:

```
$.getJSON(domainA/csrf, callback)
```

which was ending up each time with a new session and a new CSRF token for it.

The solution was to use `cors_ajax_call` function except `$.getJSON`, defined as below:

```
var cors_ajax_call = function(address, callback){

  $.ajax({
      url: address,
      context: document.body,
      xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
      }
  }).success(callback);
}
```

Thank you for your input! Hope this help someone :)